# How to install games using setup.exe flle in ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, software-installation

I have assassins creed 2 setup file, setup.exe I tried playonlinux but i got this error: "the program setup.tmp has encountered a serious problem and needs to be closed. we are sorry for the inconvenience". Please anyone help. how can i install this game ??

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install any windows application on Linux you need to use [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/)

or, a similar tool.
Otherwise, you can run windows virtual machine on Linux.

For gaming on Linux check [Proton](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/Proton/)

Edit: Seems your setup file is corrupted, check on windows first.

Comment: Regarding WINE: It seems that the OP is already trying on WINE. PlayOnLinux is a front end for WINE.

Comment: i have wine installed and i tested the setup on windows it worked verry well.

Answer (score 0):

here are the ones available on steam : https://store.steampowered.com/search/?term=Assassin%27s%20Creed

"I don't want to switch to steam"

well, you're wrong, Steam actually cares about linux and allows you to play your windows game on linux.

it is as beginner-friendly as it gets :

open steam, go to "Steam" -> "Settings" :

[image: access steam settings]

go to the last tab ("Steam Play") :

[image: steam play options]

and turn on "Steam Play" (proton) for all games like I have.

then you can just install and play the game as you would under windows.

happy gaming! :)