# Error when installing Assassin's Creed 2

Tags: 18.04, wine, games, playonlinux

Have you guys ever installed Assassin's Creed 2 on Ubuntu, currently I am trying to install Assassins Creed 2 with a setup.exe in my Ubuntu 18.04, but I am getting this error:

> "program error: the setup.tmp has encountered a serious problem and
>   needs to close . we are sorry for the inconvenience."

I have installed wine, it's wine 3. Please help me with these. How to install it? I've also tried with playonlinux but it just says "playonlinux is installing your application", and then nothing happens. I have tested this setup.exe on Windows 7 and Windows 10 and it's working but not in my Ubuntu system.

Comment: Just copy/paste windows files to Ubuntu and run it.

Comment: which windows files ??

Comment: When you run `setup.exe`, it will install game files in *Program Files* or *Program Files (x86)* folder. Just find there Assasin's creed, copy it to Ubuntu and run the main executable

Comment: By the way, crossposting is not considered as a good example here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install games using setup.exe flle in ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1128720/how-to-install-games-using-setup-exe-flle-in-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: @Olimjon i copied assassins creed 2 file from windows and its working but after some time the game screen stops and an error appears in my terminal that says : `003a:err:ntdll:RtlpWaitForCriticalSection section 0x7f1754a0 "wined3d_main.c: wined3d_cs" wait timed out in thread 003a, blocked by 0039, retrying (60 sec)
Autodumper failed to send dumpfile. No connection availeble
something went wrong when dumping, dump server is not running?`

Comment: what should i do now ??